# Set or Save checkbox value in payment method configuration template

Tags: php, html, checkbox, smarty, cs-cart

In CS Cart (PHP & MySQL based shopping cart) I'm trying to add configuration fields for a payment method.

Text input fields get saved after input. But with checkbox they do not.

In the HTML template (.tpl) file for the payment method I have set this checkbox:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="enable_test">Test?</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="payment_data[processor_params][enable_test]" id="enable_test" value="{$processor_params.enable_test}">
    </div>
</div>
```

The checkbox is shown on the coonfiguration area. But the checkbox state is not set after checking it and saving the config.

The values in text fields get set easily:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="key">{__("key")}:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="payment_data[processor_params][key]" id="key" value="{$processor_params.key}"  size="60">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to save the input value for the checkbox? Is my HTML not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be probably something like that:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="enable_test">Test?</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="payment_data[processor_params][enable_test]" id="enable_test" value="{$processor_params.enable_test}" {if isset($processor_params.enable_test) and ($processor_params.enable_test neq '')checked="checked"{/if}>
    </div>
</div>
```

For checkbox it is not enough to assign only value, but you also need to set checked state if you want it to be checked.